# Does Backwards admit a Monad instance?

Tags: haskell, monads

I just asked this on haskell-cafe, but I figure I might as well ask here too. Is the following `Monad` instance for [`Backwards m`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html) valid?

```
{-# Language RecursiveDo #-}

import Control.Applicative.Backwards
import Control.Monad.Fix

instance MonadFix m => Monad (Backwards m) where
  m >>= f = Backwards $
    do
      fin <- forwards (f int)
      int <- forwards m
      pure fin
```

If so, could I also add this?

```
instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (Backwards m) where
  mfix f = Backwards $ mfix (forwards . f)
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not valid; the monad laws at best hold in some approximate fashion. As [Petr Pudlák's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299500/1477667) shows, `Backwards m >>= f` does not behave very nicely when `f` is strict in its argument.

According to the monad laws,

```
pure () >>= (\() -> m)   =   m
```

But with this instance, if I'm not mistaken,

```
pure () >>= (\() -> m) = Backwards $ do
  fin <- forwards (int `seq` m)
  int <- pure ()
  pure fin
  = Backwards $ fmap fst $ mfix $ \ ~(_, int) -> do
     fin <- forwards (int `seq` m)
     pure (fin, ())
```

If the underlying monad is "strict" (i.e., its `>>=` is strict in its left operand), this will diverge.

Answer (score 2):

For this `f` would need to be lazy, that is, the effect must not depend on the argument. The [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html#t:MonadFix) say

> `mfix f` executes the action `f` only once, with the eventual output fed back as the input. Hence `f` should not be strict, for then `mfix f` would diverge.

Buf if `f` in your case `m >>= f` will be strict, then so will be the block passed to `mfix`.

Let's consider a practical example where `m` is `readLine >>= putStrLn`. Reversing the order would mean "print the data, then read it". Unless the effect of the function behind `>>=` doesn't depend on the input, this diverges.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this limitation, which greatly limits the utility of the instance. What's not yet clear to me is whether this limitation affects its *validity*.

Comment: Okay, I think I see how this breaks things now. I posted an answer I suspect proves it.

Comment: I hear GHC 8.0 will support time travel with respect to `IO`.